# How pass by reference works without `ref` keyword in `System.Windows.Forms` controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pass-by-reference, ref

Am wondering how pass by reference works without `ref` keyword in `System.Windows.Forms` controls.

Here is the code I have tried so far

```
ChangeProperties(button1); //Call the method without ref keyword
```

Here is the method

```
public void ChangeProperties(Button btn)
{
  // Code that changes the properties
}
```

When I call the above method by passing button without `ref` keyword, the properties of the original button keeps changing.

I also tried the below method with `int`

```
int j=10;
ChangeValue(j);// Value doesn't change without ref keyword
```

And following is the method.

```
public static int ChangeValue(int i)
{
    i = 0;
    return i;
}
```

Can anyone tell me how this is happening?

Comment: _CLR via C#_ by Jeffrey Richter is the book that helped me understand many questions similar to this one regarding to .NET. In this book, when explaining the **ref** keyword in the first several chapters, it has a sample to demonstrate what you can do by passing a reference type by ref (using **ref** keyword), very impressive.

Answer (score 4):

`Button` is a reference type, so even though you are *not* passing **by** reference, you are passing **a** reference (by value). In other words, a copy of the object is not created, a "pointer" (to use the C++ term) to it is passed to the function.

Thus, when you change its properties, those changes are reflected in the original object. Note that assigning the parameter would *not* reflect in the calling method.

`int` is a value type, so a copy *is* made before passing (unless passed by `ref`). Thus, changes (assignment) do not propagate back to the caller.

To clarify a response in the comments:

You cannot pass a reference type *object* by value, in the sense of having the runtime create a copy before passing it. However, the reference itself *is* passed by value (which is why assignment will not propagate to the caller). You can also explicitly create a copy using `Object.MemberwiseClone` (and similar methods) and pass *that* reference by value. That function in particular makes a shallow copy though, so be aware of that when using it.

Comment: There is a great article about this, let me try and dig it out. Here it is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/01/21/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx

Comment: Though I don't have a requirement to ask this, but on curiosity I am asking - Can I change the pass by reference to pass by value(like int) on calling the method for **Button**? @BradleyDotNET